# Set character set to multi byte by using code

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, multibyte

Is there a way to set the character set to multi byte in code. By that I mean without going into the properties of the compiler and setting it. I mean it by, well...in code. :p

Comment: Character set for what?  Do you mean the character set the compiler is using to parse your code?

Comment: It's possible to write code that supports multiple character sets with the choice (or choices) being made based on information supplied at run time. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Maybe you mean for a string literal?

Answer (score 1):

look at wcstombs() or perhaps WideCharToMultiByte()

Answer (score 0):

There are [#defines that control how things are compiled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z097dxa(VS.71).aspx):

```
#define _MBCS
```